# Finding the right JavaScript thermal printer

Tags: wifi, wireless, printer

I am wondering if anyone has any good suggestions on a JavaScript friendly thermal printer. We have thousands of items in our warehouse and no inventory system. I do have the inventory software almost finished.

The last step I have is when clicking "Print Label", it should print an actual label.

## What I need

We have 15 work stations, and I need each one to be able to print from Safari browser on an iPad, printing a label to a Wi-Fi label writer at that work station.

## What I figured

Brother (The printer company) has some really nice printers, but they do not work with JavaScript.

Dymo, although it supports JavaScript, only has one Wi-Fi printer, which is rather cheap and does not work with iOS browser. They also have terrible documentation, well actually next to none, and they do not offer a community forum on their site.

Zebra seems to support JavaScript quite well, but from what I have seen, only through their own private web browser, which is not supported on iOS.

There is not much for tutorials when it comes to labelwriting with JavaScript.

Any suggestions, or personal experiences would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the JavaScript limitation. You do a web service which communicates with the printer using whatever technology is the more appropriate, and then you call the web service from the browser. So what's the real problem here?

Comment: Well the problem I am running into is that I need javascript to invoke the printer through a SDK. So its not necessarily a limitation on the java script rather I am trying to find a thermal printer that **A: supports ios connection, and B: includes a javascript SDK. **

Comment: I'm hoping maybe someone else has had an experience in setting this up and would have some recommendations on a printer type to go with that would work for the given scenario. I haven't seen much. I think Zebra seems to be the best from my own research, but they require their specific browser in order to invoke the code. Which at this time does not support IOS.

Comment: I still don't understand. You can use the thermal printer as any other printer with virtually any language, including JavaScript (with Node.js extensions such as [node-printer](https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer)). So what *exactly* are you trying to achieve? Do it from the browser? Why would you do it, instead of having a web service, which seems to be a more straightforward and easy approach?